# Use FTP4J to resume upload progress and also get how many percent uploaded

Tags: java, ftp

Any one have any example how to upload with ftp4j that support resume and also how to show progress bar?

Answer (score 0):

I have just implemented a sort of following code.

I discovered that **if you use compressed streams**, you cannot rely on the transferred bytes reported by the listener, because the server can wait for further data in order to decode the previous received blocks.

Hovewer, even if streams are plains, in some cases of lost connection you still cannot rely on the total transferred bytes as reported by the listener. So, I finally realized that the best way is to ask server how many bytes it received.

In my template, the temporal redundancy is more general and involves the control connection with the FTP server. You could limit the while loop to the data connection, i.e. the upload.

```
FTPClient ftpClient = null;
long writtenBytes;
boolean isCompletedStartingDelete = false; // Our policy is overwrite at first
for (int attempt = 0; attempt < MAX_ATTEMPTS; attempt++) {
   try {
      ftpClient = getFTPClient();
      configureFtpClient(ftpClient);
      doLogin(ftpClient);  
      ftpClient.changeDirectory(remoteDirectory);

      if (!isCompletedStartingDelete) { // Our policy is overwrite at first
         try {
             ftpClient.deleteFile(file);
             isCompletedStartingDelete = true;
         } catch (FTPException e) {
             // Maybe you should check if this exception is really thrown for file not existing.
             isCompletedStartingDelete = true;
         }
      }

      try { 
         writtenBytes = ftpClient.fileSize(fileName);
      } catch (Exception e) { 
         writtenBytes = 0;
      }

      if (ftpClient.isResumeSupported()) {
         // With this template you also could use APPEND
         ftpClient.upload(file, writtenBytes, listener);
      } else {
         ftpClient.upload(file, listener);
      }  
   } catch (FTPAbortException e) {
      // User Aborted operation
      break;
   } catch (Exception e) {
      if (attempt == MAX_ATTEMPTS) { // Or in general lastLoop
         throw e;
      } else {
         // Mask failure
         // LOG
      }
   } finally {
      if (ftpClient != null && ftpClient.isConnected()) {
         try { ftpClient.disconnect(); } catch (Throwable t) { /* LOG */ } 
   }  
}
```